# How do I formulate same response on positive & negative value of the same number?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

[image: Progress so far]

Current Formula so far

```
=IF(A1>=99;"Exceeded Suspension Level";IF(A1>=69;"Exceeded Alert Level";IF(A1<=68;"Within Alert Level";IF(A1<=-99;"Exceeded Suspension Level";IF(A1<=-69;"Exceeded Alert Level";IF(A1>=-68;"Within Alert Level"))))))
```

Need help in getting same response but in negative value. 
For instance,

- 68 & below OR 0 to -68  ="Within Alert Level"
- Inclusively between 69 and 98 OR -69 to -98 ="Exceeded Alert Level"
- 99 & Above OR -99 and higher ="Exceeded Suspension Level"

Code not working for negative values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the ABS function ...

```
=IF(ABS(A1)>=99,"Exceeded Suspension Level",IF(ABS(A1)>=69,"Exceeded Alert Level",IF(ABS(A1)<=68,"Within Alert Level")))
```

[image]

Comment: @csanjose that is system language dependent. `,` is the more generally used.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
=if(ABS(A1)>=99;"Exceeded Suspension Level";if(ABS(A1)>=69;"Exceeded Alert Level";if(abs(A1)<=68;"Within Alert Level")))
```